# JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of com.example.package.XXX out of START_ARRAY token

Tags: java, android, firebase

Estoy intentando usar FIREBASE en Android y he subido mi JSON creado en mi cuenta FIREBASE, pero algo que no entiendo es que nose si me coje mal el JSON, o la parte de "Retrieving Data" del Firebase la estoy haciendo mal, aqui os paso el JSON:

```
{
  "Persona": [
    {
      "nombre": "X",
      "apellido": "XX",
      "ciudad": "XXX",
      "hijoList": [
        {
          "nombreHijo": "XXXX",
          "edadHijo": "XXXXX"
        }
       ]
},
{......}
```

Me conecta y me hace un snapshot sin ningun problema, lo muestro por toast y me conecta bien, pero a la hora de usar mi clase Persona para obtener el nombre y apellido, hay algo que da error, os enseño mi clase Persona:

```
public class Persona{

private String nombre;      
private String apellido;     
private String ciudad;     

private ArrayList<Hijo> hijoList;  // Clase hijo con nombre y edad como atributos

public Persona(){
    //empty default constructor, necessary for Firebase to be able to deserialize Persona
}
```

Y a continuacion el codigo simple que por si acaso lo pongo por si no he entendido bien la API FB:

```
firebase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            System.out.println("El numero total son: " + dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount());
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Persona post = postSnapshot.getValue(Persona.class);
                System.out.println("JSON FIREBASE: "+post.getNombre() + " - " + post.getApellido());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(SplashActivity.this, "No se cargaron los personajes debido a: "
                    + firebaseError, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Cual es el problema? puede ser porque el JSON tiene Persona como array? Gracias por adelantado

Comment: @MMariscal, ve mi respuesta, si tu objeto tiene todos los get correspondientes, edita tu pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error era que en el JSON esta compuesto por un `array` de `Persona`, entonces en el

`firebase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){....});`

hay que cambiarlo por:

`firebase.child("Persona").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){....});`

Espero que os haya ayudado

Comment: Exactamente amigo, mucho cuidado con los ´[ ]´ no son lo mismo que ´{ }´ literalmente jejeje

Answer (score 0):

Veo que tu implementación es correcta:

```
 <Clase> post = postSnapshot.getValue(<Clase>.class);
```

Pero tu clase `persona` no contiene los métodos `get()` para `nombre` y `apellido`:

```
    public class Persona{

            private String nombre;      
            private String apellido;     
            private String ciudad;     
...
...
...

            public String getNombre(){
                   return nombre;
            } 

            public String getApellido(){
                   return apellido;
            } 
        }
```

Más información: [Firebase, obteniendo datos.](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/retrieving-data.html) (inglés)

Comment: Disculpa no los habia puesto dando a entender que ya los tenia puestos, gracias de todas maneras

Comment: Por cierto puede ser que afecte porque Persona sea un array? o por algun error de capitulosList? muchas gracias